# Get SAP System Date

Tags: vba, sap-gui

Using SAP scripting, I'm trying to figure out a way of obtaining SAP's current system date.

If I following System > Status..., there is a field displaying the SAP system's current time, but unfortunately there is no field for the current date. Code below.

```
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set SAPConnection = SAPApp.Children(0)
Set session = SAPConnection.Children(0)

Dim systemDate, systemTime As String

session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[4]/menu[11]").Select
systemTime = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtSYST-UZEIT").Text
'systemDate = .....
```

[image]

I feel like there must be a simple way of getting the system date, but after hours of searching the web I have come up with nothing. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

I have found one solution, sort of. It's not the simplest way, but I can save a variant in one of SAP's transaction (IW37N) so that it auto populates a date and a time field with a dynamic value of now upon entry. Once the variant is saved, I can use SAP scripting to access the transaction > access the variant > access the two dynamic fields (code below). Again, not really the simplest option, so I'm open to hearing better ideas.

```
'Connect to SAP

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set SAPConnection = SAPApp.Children(0)
Set session = SAPConnection.Children(0)

'Enter Transaction

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/NIW37N"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

'Select Variant

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[17]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtV-LOW").Text = "TEST001"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtENVIR-LOW").Text = ""
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtENAME-LOW").Text = ""
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtAENAME-LOW").Text = ""
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtMLANGU-LOW").Text = ""
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press

'Select Dates Tab

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_TABBLOCK1/tabpS_TAB5").Select

'Get Field Values

Dim systemDate, systemTime As String
systemDate = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_TABBLOCK1/tabpS_TAB5/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_TABBLOCK1:RI_ORDER_OPERATION_LIST:1500/ctxtS_ISDD-LOW").Text
systemTime = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_TABBLOCK1/tabpS_TAB5/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_TABBLOCK1:RI_ORDER_OPERATION_LIST:1500/ctxtS_ISDZ-LOW").Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sergii was right. The problem is that the same dates are hidden. Thus, the variables are not available. I wanted to know, so I signed in to SAP shortly before midnight. It will look like that:

[image]

The script could look like this:

```
'...
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[1]/menu[11]").select 
on error resume next
LAST_LOGON_DATE = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtLAST_LOGON_DATE").text
SESSION_START_DATE = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtSESSION_START_DATE").text 
SYST_DATE = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtSYST-DATUM").setFocus
on error goto 0
session.findById("wnd[1]").close
if SESSION_START_DATE = "" then SESSION_START_DATE = LAST_LOGON_DATE
if SYST_DATE = "" then SYST_DATE = SESSION_START_DATE 
msgbox  LAST_LOGON_DATE & " / " & SESSION_START_DATE  & " / " & SYST_DATE
'...
```

Regards,
ScriptMan

Comment: Oooooohh, this make sense. Thanks for investigating this! I would have never thought to check to see if this field appears.

Answer (score 1):

Let you try this:
systemDate = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtSYST-DATUM").Text
You can see for details there:
https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1095191

Regards
Sergii

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried this and it doesn't work. I assume it doesn't work because there is no field with the technical name of DATUM displayed in my current session. It works for the time value (UZEIT) because that field is one of the fields displayed.